# DD_belatedPNG and DD_roundies having conflict with Cufon in Opera

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I am facing strange problem in opera while using cufon with dd_belatedPNG and dd_roundies.

every thing works fine in every browser execept opera. 
Once I remove below two lines it cufon works with opera as well. but I need dd_roundies and png fix as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/DD_roundies_0.0.2a-min.js"></script>
```

But I need to make cufon work with dd_roundies and png fix.
no javascript error. every thing works fine in all browsers except opera.

Any Idea?

here is whole test page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/cufon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fonts/3/ergoe-light-cufon.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.8a-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/DD_roundies_0.0.2a-min.js"></script>

<style>
h1 {font-size:136px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test Heading</h1>

<script>
 Cufon.set('fontFamily', 'ErgoeLight').replace('h1');
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem myself. 
I have placed a browser detection check on dd_belatedPNG.js file

```
if (BrowserDetect.browser != 'Opera')
            document.documentElement.firstChild.insertBefore(screenStyleSheet, document.documentElement.firstChild.firstChild);
```

that is the browser detecting code which is usedin ifcondition above

```
var BrowserDetect = {
    init: function () {
        this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "An unknown browser";
        this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent)
            || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion)
            || "an unknown version";
        this.OS = this.searchString(this.dataOS) || "an unknown OS";
    },
    searchString: function (data) {
        for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            var dataString = data[i].string;
            var dataProp = data[i].prop;
            this.versionSearchString = data[i].versionSearch || data[i].identity;
            if (dataString) {
                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) != -1)
                    return data[i].identity;
            }
            else if (dataProp)
                return data[i].identity;
        }
    },
    searchVersion: function (dataString) {
        var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
        if (index == -1) return;
        return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index+this.versionSearchString.length+1));
    },
    dataBrowser: [
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Chrome",
            identity: "Chrome"
        },
        {   string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "OmniWeb",
            versionSearch: "OmniWeb/",
            identity: "OmniWeb"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Apple",
            identity: "Safari",
            versionSearch: "Version"
        },
        {
            prop: window.opera,
            identity: "Opera"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "iCab",
            identity: "iCab"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "KDE",
            identity: "Konqueror"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Firefox",
            identity: "Firefox"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.vendor,
            subString: "Camino",
            identity: "Camino"
        },
        {       // for newer Netscapes (6+)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Netscape",
            identity: "Netscape"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "MSIE",
            identity: "Explorer",
            versionSearch: "MSIE"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Gecko",
            identity: "Mozilla",
            versionSearch: "rv"
        },
        {       // for older Netscapes (4-)
            string: navigator.userAgent,
            subString: "Mozilla",
            identity: "Netscape",
            versionSearch: "Mozilla"
        }
    ],
    dataOS : [
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Win",
            identity: "Windows"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Mac",
            identity: "Mac"
        },
        {
               string: navigator.userAgent,
               subString: "iPhone",
               identity: "iPhone/iPod"
        },
        {
            string: navigator.platform,
            subString: "Linux",
            identity: "Linux"
        }
    ]

};
BrowserDetect.init();
```